# How long does the spmatrix take to create contiguity matrixes?

Tags: matrix, regression, stata, spatial, spatial-regression

I've been trying to do spatial regressions for a paper. Now I have the problem that I need contiguity or inverse distance matrixes for this. I've been using an official shapefile for the communities in Germany for this. Making it a few thousand cases.

Now I've been running the command "spmatrix create contiguity Wc" on my computer for two hours, but it looks more like Stata crashed than it'll ever finish the calculations. I've been using Stata 15 IC.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to restrain the matrix creation process so it'll go faster - like only allow a certain distance?

Comment: I have no experience with this problem but it doesn't seem surprising that the calculation is slow. That's a massive matrix. There can't be a hook here, as I understand it, as the code would have to calculate a distance before it could tell whether it is too large.

Comment: You have a problem but I don't think it's a problem that allows more than guesses, so I think this is off-topic here.